# Is Dijkstra's algorithm a heuristic?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, heuristics

Can someone explain to me whether *Dijkstra's algorithm* is  **heuristic** or not and **how this algorithm works**

Answer (score 2):

No. For this reason, the A* search algorithm is used, which is made on the principles of Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm to provide a faster solution when faced with the problem of finding the shortest path between two nodes. It achieves this by introducing a heuristic element to help decide the next node to consider as it moves along the path. The A* algorithm uses a heuristic function to help decide which path to follow next.

---

One of the drawbacks with Dijkstra's algorithm is that it can (and will) evaluate paths that will never provide the shortest option. The heuristic function provides an estimate of the minimum cost between a given node and the target node. The algorithm will combine the actual cost from the start node - referred to as g(n) - with the estimated cost to the target node - referred to as h(n) - and uses the result to select the next node to evaluate. This is explained in more detail in the step-by-step method that follows.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn’t, it is an exact method.

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) explains well how it works.